# Preventing block of Thymeleaf to run

Tags: thymeleaf

The code below is for a classifieds like website that takes care of pagation. Right now if the city page has no ads I get the following error.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#numbers.sequence(pager.startPage, pager.endPage)" (city:74)
```

Is there a block style if statement Thymeleaf so I can prevent anything from pagation to run if no ads exists for that city?

The relevant code

```
<div class="row">
    <div th:if="${ads.totalPages != 1}"
        class="form-group col-md-11 pagination-centered">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li th:class="${ads.number == 0} ? disabled"><a
                class="pageLink" th:href="1">&laquo;</a></li>
            <li th:class="${ads.number == 0} ? disabled"><a
                class="pageLink" th:href="${ads.number}">&larr;</a></li>
            <li
                th:class="${ads.number == (page - 1)} ? 'active pointer-disabled'"
                th:each="page : ${#numbers.sequence(pager.startPage, pager.endPage)}">
                <a class="pageLink"
                th:href="@{${'/' + cityForPage + '/{page}'}(page=${page})}"
                th:text="${page}"></a>
            </li>
            <li th:class="${ads.number + 1 == ads.totalPages} ? disabled">
                <a class="pageLink"
                th:href="@{${'/' + cityForPage + '/{page}'}(page=${ads.number + 2})}">&rarr;</a>
            </li>
            <li th:class="${ads.number + 1 == ads.totalPages} ? disabled">
                <a class="pageLink"
                th:href="@{${'/' + cityForPage + '/{page}'}(page=${ads.totalPages})}">&raquo;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`<th:block />`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag)?  You can surround a section of html and put a th:if in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate on the city outside of your posted code block, and for example, you have something similar to a `Collection` property called `ads` on your `city` object, you can do:

```
  <div th:each="city : ${cities}" th:remove="tag">
    <div class="row" th:if="${!#lists.isEmpty(city.ads)}">
        <div th:if="${ads.totalPages != 1}"
            class="form-group col-md-11 pagination-centered">
        <!-- the rest of your HTML... -->
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or, if you're calling a service, you'd just replace the `city.ads` and the outer loop with the relevant call(s).  In any case, you'd probably be checking whether some collection or list is not empty.

Aside: I'd rename your `page` variable to `pageNumber` or `pageNo` to be more clear for the next person.